# Android Application Development: Automatic Margin?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

How can I assign each view an automatic margin?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want each of these buttons to have the same amount of space between them.
Now I could just put a layout_marginTop and a layout_marginBottom attribute in each of the tags and set their values to what I want them to be, but isn't there an easier way to do this?

Can I somehow automatically set each view's margin in my LinearLayout to a specific value without having to type it in every tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **layout weight** of the object

Set each of the buttons to have an equal layout weight and then set each of their heights to **match_parent**

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: That isn't the same as a margin of space around the views is it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Craigy is kind of right, though. It's not quite what I am looking for. It kind of does solve my problem, as I do get an even amount of margin around every view, but if anyone knows a method to define a margin for all views in a LinearLayout, I would still appreciate it if they posted it. :) Thank you anyways.

Comment: I am assuming that he is trying to evenly space them by using the margins.